# Not able to install VirtualBox on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, virtualbox, macos-high-sierra

I have been trying to install VirtualBox on Mac os High Sierra but installation is failing. I tried all the steps provided here [Virtualbox not installing on High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546192/virtualbox-not-installing-on-high-sierra) but nothing worked for me. Basically, while installing, it is not asking me if I should allow outside app from Oracle or not. After the failed installation, I see that the VirtualBox still got installed but when I start a vm, it errors out and gives all sorts of other errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you know the installation has failed? In what way has it failed? I would expect Oracle to be a trusted developer so depending on your system settings you may not be asked for permission.